# Permission denied using mysql in Mac Terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

When attempting to do anything with mysql I am met with a

> permission denied

For example

```
adamshaw$ mysql> -u root -p
-bash: -u: Permission denied

(base) Adams-MacBook-Pro:mysql adamshaw$ mysql> --skip-grant-tables
-bash: --skip-grant-tables: Permission denied
```

How do I grant myself permission to my own mysql?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about why you believe `mysql>` with the ending `>` is a valid command? More often than not, `mysql` is the command you'd be looking for, unless you have some aliasing set up. In the context of a `bash` prompt, the `>` token indicates that the output of the preceding command should be redirected to a file.

Comment: I get a 'command not found' when I don't use '>'

Comment: That means that either the mysql client is not installed, or the path to the executable is not in the default paths in your terminal. Try changing to the directory where the mysql executable is installed and then run it again (without the >)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding **chmod 755** to the beginning of the code line. 
This helped me with trying to run python scripts via terminal. 
May work for MySQL too.